# An identity relating partial derivatives to a function

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, approximation

I saw somewhere that given a function f(x,y) you can approximate with the following

Δf≈ ∂f/∂x * Δx + ∂f/∂y * Δy

Can someone explain why this works and where this came from? 
Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with the Taylor expansion ? In 1D ? In 2D ?

Comment: Cf. [Chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Multivariable_case)

Comment: I know the very basics of the Taylor Expansion and haven't seen it used in multi-variable calculus. For the Chain Rule I looked at the page but can't connect the dots. Is there any basic way to get to this point? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would you agree $\Delta f\approx \partial f/\partial x  \times \Delta x$ if $y$ is constant?

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Then we can treat f(x,y) as f(x) and I am comfortable with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Taylor on the first variable,

$$g(x,y):=f(x+\Delta x, y)\approx f(x, y)+\dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\Delta x.$$

Then using it on the second variable,
$$f(x+\Delta x,y+\Delta y)=g(x,y+\Delta y)\approx g(x,y)+\dfrac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y}\Delta y
\\\approx f(x, y)+\dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\Delta x+\dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\Delta y+\dfrac{\partial^2f(x,y)}{\partial x\,\partial y}\Delta x\Delta y.$$

The last term is negligible.

Comment: Thanks for you help! The only problem is that I don't really understand the Taylor Series for multivariable functions. Sorry if I wasn't clear about that. Although this does make sense I was wondering if there was any approach that could start from the beginning or maybe explain the Taylor Series as an alternative. Thanks for this though!

Comment: @BOSSrobot: I am not sure you understood or believed my answer. It only uses the univariate Taylor development, twice.

Comment: Oh I see it now. That makes sense you are treating the other variable as a constant each time you use the Taylor Series. I think I was blinded by the two variables being present. Thanks for the help!